# Activity backstack with condition

Tags: android

If I have `6` activities say `Activity1 ,Activity2, Activity3, Activity4, Activity5, Activity6` the flow is `Activity1-> Activity2-> Activity3-> Activity4-> Activity5-> Activity6`. I want to go to `Activity3` from `Activity6` only if I am on `Activity6`. if I am at `Activity4` or `Activity5` then normal back stack will work. I don't want to clear the activity from top unless I'm at 6th. So please read what I am asking before marking it as duplicate

Comment: If you are on 6th and press the back button, you want to go 3rd one.

or if you are on the 5th and press the back button then the 4th one should come.

Comment: Start activities 4, 5 and 6 using startActivityForResult. If you close 6 put an extra on the closing intent indicating 6. In 5  in onActivity result grab the 6 and close putting the 6 also. In 4 do the same.